# Labels array dimension is correct but still gets Error when checking target

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The shape of my labels array is `(5000, 10)`,
But still gets error

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Here is my network model:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(3072, )))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Can you make a example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: When do you get that error? After compiling or after calling `model.fit()`?